# LinkedStack and its template class

Tags: c++, stack

So, I was starting coding over the LinkedStack for myself, and I finally narrow down where the error occurred but I do not know how to fix it. I'll post my code and the error here, see if anyone could figure out. Thanks

**LinkedNode.h**

```
#pragma once
#include"LinkedStack.h"
#include<iostream>

template<class T>
class LinkedNode
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedNode<T>& obj);
    friend class LinkedStack<T>;

    public:
        LinkedNode(T val);
        T GetElement() const {return element;}
        LinkedNode<T>* GetNext() const {return next;}
        void SetElement(T val) {element = val;}
        void SetNext(LinkedNode<T>* val) {next = val;}

    private:
        T element;
        LinkedNode<T>* next;
};

template<class T>
LinkedNode<T>::LinkedNode(T val):next(nullptr)
{
    element = val;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedNode<T>& obj)
{
    os << "Element added is: " << obj.element;
    return os;
}
```

**LinkedStack.h**

```
#pragma once
#include<cassert>
#include"LinkedNode.h"

template<class T>
class LinkedStack
{
    public:
        LinkedStack();
        int GetSize() const {return size;}
        /*void SetSize(int val) {size = val;}
        bool IsTmpty() const {return size == 0;}
        void Push(T val);*/

    private:
        LinkedNode<T>* head; // This is where the errors occur, it does not accept
                                 // the generic type T for the LinkedNode class !!!
        int size;
};

template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack():head(nullptr), size(0)
{
}
```

This is the errors complained by VS2012:

```
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    16
Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    16
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\test\linkedstack\linkedstack.h    16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a circular dependency between headers: you have header A include header B, which in turn includes A (which in turn includes B, ...).

In your example, you don't need those #includes at all - you can get by with forward declarations. In `LinkedNode.h`, replace

```
#include"LinkedStack.h"
```

with

```
template <typename T> class LinkedStack;
```

and similarly in `LinkedStack.h`, use forward declaration for `LinkedNode`.

Comment: so you can use the forward declarations instead of #include header file ? Or is it only used in a circular dependency between headers ?

Comment: You can use forward declarations where an incomplete class is sufficient. For example, you could use pointers or references to an incomplete class, or declare one as a friend. But you can't, say, create instances of that class, or access its members. Forward declarations are often necessary in order to break circular dependencies, but that's not the only situation where they can be used.